# Implementing Dependency Injection with a singleton

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am using WPF with `Entity Framework 6` (DB first), `Caliburn.Micro`, and `MEF`.

I am trying to implement `IoC` in my project. I am an absolute beginner in `IoC`, and unfortunately, I cant find too many examples where `MEF` is used with `Repository Pattern`.

So I have a few repositories, and I have created my Generic Unit of Work like this:

```
class GenericUoW : IUoW, IDisposable
{
    protected readonly DbContext _ctx;

    public GenericUoW(DbContext context)
    {
        _ctx = context;
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ctx.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My actual Unit of Work classes are implemented like this:

```
class InvoiceUoW : GenericUoW, IInvoiceUoW
{
    public InvoiceUoW(DbContext _ctx) : base(_ctx)
    {
        salesrepo = new SaleRepository(_ctx);
        itemsrepo = new ItemRepository(_ctx);
        materialrepo = new MaterialRepository(_ctx);
        raterepo = new RateRepository(_ctx);
        clientrepo = new ClientRepository(_ctx);
        taxrepo = new TaxRepository(_ctx);
        stockhistoryrepo = new StockHistoryRepository(_ctx);
        proformarepo = new ProformaRepository(_ctx);
    }

    public ISaleRepository salesrepo { get; private set; }
    public IItemRepository itemsrepo { get; private set; }
    public IMaterialRepository materialrepo { get; private set; }
    public IRateRepository raterepo { get; private set; }
    public IClientRepository clientrepo { get; private set; }
    public ITaxRepository taxrepo { get; private set; }
    public IStockHistoryRepository stockhistoryrepo { get; private set; }
    public IProformaRepository proformarepo { get; private set; }
}
```

Now, in my `ViewModel`, I am doing something like this:

```
[Export(typeof(InvoiceViewModel))]    
class InvoiceViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{

    #region ctor
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public InvoiceViewModel(IInvoiceUoW invoiceUoW)
    {
        _uow = invoiceUoW;
        Clients = new BindableCollection<Client>(_uow.clientrepo.FetchAll());
    }

    #endregion

    private readonly IInvoiceUoW _uow;

    //other properties and methods
}
```

My question is related to the use of `IoC/DI` in `InvoiceUoW`. How do I implement `constructor injection` in that class? Because each of those repositories in that class has to be instantiated with the same `DataContext`. How do I make the `DataContext` a singleton? Please do note that I have several `Unit of Work` classes, each for one `viewmodel`.

Comment: You should never use EF DbContext as singleton. Each instance of your InvoiceUoW should receive it's own instance of context. By the way, EF context already follows UoW pattern, and each DbSet follows generic repository pattern, so your wrappers around it are actually quite meaningless.

Comment: `Each instance of your InvoiceUoW should receive it's own instance of context.` I get that. But how can I get all the repositories in a `UoW` to be instantiated with the same `DbContext`? When I try to do this with `MEF`, it does something equivalent to this:

`salesrepo = new SaleRepository(new DbContext());
    itemsrepo = new ItemRepository(new DbContext());
    materialrepo = new MaterialRepository(new DbContext());`

Comment: But your code shows that you instantiate your "repositories" manually, passing the same context there: `salesrepo = new SaleRepository(_ctx);`

Comment: That's how I have kept it for now, because I cant do it properly with `MEF`.

Comment: I want the `ctor` parameters to look like this:
`public InvoiceUoW(DbContext _ctx, ISaleRepository salerepo, IItemRepository itemsrepo,IMaterialRepository materialrepo, ... ) : base(_ctx)`

Comment: I undrstand what you mean, but as I remember (didn't use MEF for years) - MEF only has notion of shared (so, signleton) and non-shared (new instance per request) dependencies. Neither case fits your scenario. But even with real DI container it would be hard to do that. Which means you should just reconsider what you are doing.

Comment: Why do you want them all to use same context instance?

Comment: I want **all** repositories in **each** unit of work to use the same context instance. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the `DbContext` instance to be resolved and act like a singleton:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(); //Get it from where it belongs
var dbContext = container.GetExportedValue<DbContext>();
container.ComposeExportedValue<DbContext>(dbContext);
```

For your UoW, MEF doesn't work the same way as Unity, in MEF you rather decorate the implementing type to tell the container it should register it:

```
[Export(typeof(IUnitOfWork))]
public class MyUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
```

Comment: How do I use the `[ImportingConstructor]` in the `UnitOfWork`?

Comment: As long as its parameters are familiar with the container, publishing UoW itself to the container will make all the work for you.